# Detecting Red Green and Blue by cancelling background

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have continuous image acquisition and have a white paper at the background of the camera (facing the camera)

The image with just the white background is producing a greenish blue tinge due to light bulbs used in the room which is resulting in output as `GREEN` for the following code

```
 green = im(:,:,2);
   red = im(:,:,1);
   if sum( green(:)) > sum(red(:))
       disp('green');
   else
       disp('red');
   end
```

Is there any way to `CANCEL` the white paper background for processing only the color objects that will be placed in front of the camera ??

The Color objects will be RED, GREEN and BLUE squares

Comment: If it's a stationary object, measure the ambient color and subtract that off from your initial color read

Answer (score 1):

The way you are testing for green or red is fundamentally flawed - you need to look for the dominant colour using a suitable threshold, otherwise you will get false positives. E.g.

```
threshold = 0.7;   % determine a suitable threshold empirically
blue = sum(sum(im(:,:,3)));
green = sum(sum(im(:,:,2)));
red = sum(sum(im(:,:,1)));
total = red + green + blue;
if (red / total > threshold)
    disp("red");
elseif (green / total > threshold)
    disp("green");
elseif (blue / total > threshold)
    disp("blue");
else
    disp("indeterminate colour");
end
```

Comment: On what basis should I consider the threshold ??

Comment: the resultant of `red./sum` is an array how can we compare with threshold which is a integer ??

Comment: Sorry - hastily written untested code - it's meant to illustrate a concept rather than be a ready-to-use code fragment - hopefully it's now fixed. As it says in the comment, you will need to determine threshold empirically as it will depend on your particular system. Start with 0.7 and see how it goes...

Comment: I tried something similar to this after u laid out the initial concept. However in my case I found that threshold ranges from color to color so instead of writing just a greater than condition I tried with ranges of threshold. Thanks for the help.

I suppose cancellation of background (the white background that has a greenish shade)is what I need currently Could you please help me out in the concept ??

Comment: I think you cannot just take any threshold value randomly. There might  be some procedures of knowing a threshold value for a image, say for example creating or drawing histogram of image and choosing threshold value to be the minimum point between the two largest peak in histograms.